# Оптимизация js кода

Tags: javascript

Дело в чем, добавил парочку интервалов на страничку setInterval, слайдер и т.д. И уже страничка неадекватно себя ведет "глючит" слегка, проблему не могу понять, оставляю даже всего один setInterval на странице, а уже как-то не так сайт себя ведёт, хотя ничего плохого не происходит. В интервале идет просто b++ if (b>c) b=1; собственно цикл бесконечный для слайдера.

Так прописываю setInterval:

```
var b = 1;
var c = 10;
var time = 3000;

function loadednext() {
    b++;
    if (b > c) {
        b = 1;
    }
}
var inter = setinterval(loadednext, time);
```

Comment: Позвольте угадать - setInterval пишется с параметрами в кавычках, я прав?

Если да - переписывайте, если нет - предоставьте код

Comment: я исправил как использую, а по поводу обойтись без можно подробнее?

Comment: не ужели функция setTimeout меньше влияет на производительность Js кода на стороне клиента?

Comment: @Spectre setInterval сам по себе не должен тормозить страницу. Если действие должно выполняться постоянно, то использовать setTimeout, как минимум - не логично

Comment: Собственно в самом setInterval выполняется только пару смен свойств css, а так же animate

Comment: @Afimida, это неправда, замена интервала на дергающийся таймаут ровно ничего не даст. Опишите подробнее "глюки".

Comment: описываю к примеру на текст написана функция animate при наведении, если сет интервал работает, во время смены слайда animate выполняются не корректно, а так же когда страницу листаешь в низ такое чувство, что ты листаешь, слайды ну соответственно спускается не плавно. 8 гигов оперативной памяти, 4 ядра 2 гб видео. Собственно проверяю сайт на загрузку памяти в диспетчере задач память не грузит браузер. ( память проверяю т.к. js на стороне клиента идет )

Comment: При такой железке я могу сделать вывод что написано конкретно через Ж =)

По моему по другому быть не может

@Spectre - вы реально думаете что на таком железе заметны серьезные тормоза из-за пары таймеров? О_о

Единственный серьезный недостаток setInterval заключается в том, что setInterval добавляет функции в цепочку выполнения по четко заданному интервалу (что может помешать. например, корректно выполниться "итерации" другого интервала), не более того.

Тормоза от использования setInterval, при том какого рода код запускает ТС - скорее всего исключены

Comment: А вторая ссылка вообще ниочем, пример с изменением контекст выполнения функции вообще убил - причем тут interval? -_-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В большинстве случаев можно обойтись без `setInterval`

```
function someFunction() {
    ...
    setTimeout(function () {
        someFunction();
    }, 500);
}
```

[О том, как работают JavaScript таймеры](http://habrahabr.ru/post/138062/)

[JavaScript Гарден: setTimeout и setInterval](http://shamansir.github.com/JavaScript-Garden/#other.timeouts) рекомендуют избегать setInterval

Comment: function someFunction() {
    ...
    setTimeout(function () {
        someFunction();
    }, 500);
}
О том, как работают JavaScript таймеры
JavaScript Гарден: setTimeout и setInterval рекомендуют избегать setInterval
Как бы я не был удивлён, но это помогло! Спасибо большое

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите сказать что у вас используется такой код как вы написали выше и он приводил к тормозам при setInterval и без него перестал?

Либо вы чего-то недоговариваете либо я ничего не понимаю в javascript'e

Comment: Я хочу сказать что мы оба чего-то не понимаем, однако при таком подходе и если верить предложенной литературе, setTimeout не будет ломится на пролом для выполнения своей части кода, и не будет тормозить код в отличие от setInterval, ну это я ещё раз повторюсь если верить литературе, однако судя по тому, что я увидел лагов стало заметно ниже.

Comment: страница крутится уже приятнее ^_^

Comment: Минусну. Не вижу, как от этой нелепой копипасты может полегчать.

Comment: Смею предположить что у вас огромные проблемы с формулировкой вопроса, такого рожа интервал не может заметно(уловимо для человеческого взгляда, даже в дебагере разницы вы бы, практически, не заметили) тормозить, конечно если код написан не через страшную Ж и был выставлен адекватный проделываемой работе интервал.

Comment: Если будет возможность отбить себе руки обязательно сделаю, проблема вся была в этом :
background-size:cover;
-moz-background-size:cover;
именно это жестоко давило на броузер (((
Жаль минусы самому себе ставить нельзя (^_^)